# Add tier price to upsell block

Tags: magento

I searched high and low on google for this answer. I need to display the tier prices for the products that show on the upsell block in the product page.

I tried this:

```
<?php echo $this->getTierPriceHtml() ?>
```

However, it echos the tier price for the main product on the page instead of the tier prices for the products in the upsell block.

Does anyone know a work around here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're almost done

```
$this->getTierPriceHtml($_link);
```

Indeed, this method accept a parameter for the $product to show, if you don't set it it will show the price for Mage::registry('current_product') aka the main product, just pass the upsold product as argument and you're ok.

Comment: Thanks buddy! This seems to work.. +1 Vote. I should have gotten 30 myself since this info seems to be nowhere lol